# Constant constructors in Dart

Tags: oop, dart

The doubt is:

When defining a constant constructor in a subclass, it is necessary that the default constructor of the upper class is constant.

However, when the default constructor of the upper class is defined as constant, it is not necessary that the constructor of the inherited class be constant.

The codes below exemplifies the situation:

```
// Default constructor of the subclass defined as constant:

class Super_class {
  Super_class();
}

class Sub_class extends Super_class {
  const Sub_class() : super();
}
```

```
// Default constructor of the upper class defined as constant:

class Super_class {
  const Super_class();
}

class Sub_class extends Super_class {
  Sub_class() : super();
}
```

Could someone explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited.  A `const` base class constructor imposes no `const` requirements on its derived classes.

A `const` constructor means that the object must be constructible in a `const` context.  One way of thinking about it is that the object must be constructible at compilation time; it does not depend on any runtime values.  Consequently, a `const` constructor can depend *only* on other things that are `const`, including base class constructors.

Answer (score 1):

If your subclass has a `const` constructor, then it is must call a super-class `const` constructor, otherwise it won't be able to perform compile-time constant evaluation of the entire construction. The `const` superclass constructor does not need to be the unnamed (sometimes mistakenly named "default") constructor. The superclass just have to have *some* constant generative constructor that you can call.
Example:

```dart
class SuperClass {
  final int foo;
  factory SuperClass() => const SuperClass._(0);
  const SuperClass._(this.foo);
}
class Subclass {
  final int bar;
  const SubClass(int foo, this.bar) : super._(foo);
}
```

A subclass does not have to have a const constructor, even if the superclass does. The superclass *itself* can have non-constant constructors as well as constant constructors.